# Define from php

Tags: php, email

I have sendmail.php that works great. But when I trying to send mail to two email adresses and one of the come from variable mail is not send. When I go:

```
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", "luka@luka.com, luka123@luka.com");
```

works fine, bet when I try from variable I get error, mail is not send.

```
$Mail = "luka123@luka.com";
if (empty($Mail)){
    define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", "luka@luka.com");
} else {
    define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", "luka@luka.com, $Mail");
}
```

Any idea?

here is send function

```
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $mail_salji, $headers);
```

Comment: `"I get error"` - What.  Is.  The.  Error.

Comment: the third argument of define function suppose to be a Boolean - mot a string.

Comment: @IdanMagled That isn't 3 arguments, it is 2. The second just has a comma in it...

Comment: This code as posted above would produce no error. Please post the code which _does_ error, and also the error message you receive.

Comment: I actually tested your code in PHP 5.3 and it should work.

Comment: I posted send function code above, but can't poste errors because it goes via ajax, so I don' know how to see error. It just stop sending, but when I manualy enter mail adresses works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3
```

OK, after searching error on Google I find out that my hosting provider turn on magic quotes. So I can only send to email address with same domain as my site. So I have to contact my hosting provider to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought it must be because you cannot use a variable in a constant definition. But when I tested this code:

```
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL1", "luka@luka.com, luka123@luka.com");

echo WEBMASTER_EMAIL1;

$mail = 'luka123@luka.com';
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL2", "luka@luka.com, $mail");

echo '<br>';
echo WEBMASTER_EMAIL2;
```

I got this result:

```
luka@luka.com, luka123@luka.com
luka@luka.com, luka123@luka.com
```

So your problem is somewhere else.

Ajax can be tested. Just find out what the ajax call is and then call the ajax page like that in your browser. Don't forget to switch error reporting on in your ajax page.

Comment: $WebmasterEmail = luka@luka.com;  will be better?

Comment: Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3

Comment: Could that be the error you get from your ajax page? Perhaps? Well if that's the case, check: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc